# Dynamic Padding? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, padding, html

Ok. What I would like to do is to use jQuery to go through all `<span>` tags with a certain class (`.link`) and to set their `padding-right` css value to 20% of current width of the span.

I do not have any code to show because I am not good with jQuery and the rest is pretty much self-explanatory.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `css()` method with a callback function that returns the width of the currently iterated element x 0.2

```
$('span.link').css('padding-right', function() {
    return $(this).width() * 0.2;
});
```

In newer browsers you could do this with CSS as well

```
span.link { padding-right: calc(20%); }
```

Comment: Wow, fast reply! Thanks for the answer.